# Quality Score History of Specific Keywords - Adwords Script

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-ads-api

I want to create a Adwords Script which will keep track of Quality Score for specific keywords on a daily basis. The results will be stored in a Google Spreadsheet.
So, what I want is:
the first column to be the Keywords Column (which will not change)
and then each column to have the current date and the keyword's quality score.
This will run on a daily schedule so next day it should write that day's results in a new column:

```
Keywords___|__Date1___|__Date2__|_DateN_|
samplekey1_|___ 8 ____|___ 9 ___|___9___|
samplekey2_|___ 6 ____|___ 7 ___|___9___|
samplekey3_|___ 8 ____|__ 10 ___|___9___|
samplekeyN_|___ 7 ____|___ 8 ___|___8___|
```

(the numbers are the quality score of that keyword for the given date)

Is there an easy way to code that script?
What I really need is a way to check if a column is empty and if yes, to write the quality score results of the keyword in that column. Thanks for any help.